# Core Data does not seem to take updated values

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am running an update thread which updates a table using coredata.
One of the records is called last-update. But when after the update is finished I retrieve the last-update value in the main thread I get an outdated value.

I do:

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
```

before query-ing the setting again, but is there anything else I should/can do to alert the mainthread that it should check the physical table again?

Comment: Does your update thread use a separate managed object context to your fetch thread?

Comment: It does as it was suggested that that was the only thread save way of doing it. I could re-write the whole App to perform core data calls on the Main Thread but it kind of makes the design illogical. There must be a way ???

Comment: You don't need to rewrite or refactor app - but you will need to have NSManagedObjectContexts in worker thread and in main thread, with both pointing to same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. Take a look at Marcus Zarra's Core Data book - in particular, chapter 9 (Multithreading and Core Data) - for details on cross-thread communictation (by which he means having worker thread notify main thread of changes).

Comment: @Westsider-- you should move your comment to an answer.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good, and I will have a look at getting the book! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're not syncing the updates back into the main thread's NSManagedObjectController. Try adding a method like this:

```
- (void)managedContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)n {
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = /* Get context for main thread */;
        [context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:n];
    } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(managedContextDidSave:) withObject:n waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Then hook that up to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: That works! I do a lot of saves, so didn't implement the notification, as it seems to much unnecessary overhead in my case, but the solution works perfectly!